# Philosophy and actuality

Tags: nietzsche

According to the understanding of Nietzsche's superman did Hitler live up to Nietzsche ideal of the superman? (**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I am by **NO** means a Fan of Hitler this is a question of scholarly interest)

Comment: Can you unpack or develop this further? What have you found out already? What might you be reading that made this question important to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In no way.

To name but a few things, Hitler was anti-semitic; Nietzsche was quite vocally opposed to anti-semitism.  More to the point, Hitler's rise was based almost purely on *ressentiment*, the opposite of what Nietzsche would want.

Comment: Nietzsche furthermore hated and denounced the rise of anti-Semitism in Germany

Comment: Is this not a different thing than Hitler "failing to live up to the Nietche's ideal of the superman"? Is not the idea of living without fear of other's moral judgement an orthogonal concept to having hypothetically been a person whose ideas Nietsche would personally have approved of? It's also certainly true that Nietchse's writing were twisted and distorted, but this is also a different thing from Hitler demonstrating substantial personal deviations from Nietsche's own ideal.